# How to create style based on default DataGrid style?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, styles

I have custom control that extends `DataGrid`. It is called `ExtendedDataGrid`. I want to provide style for `ExtendedDataGrid` that is the same as `DataGrid`s style except it changes the template. I have tried something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControls:ExtendedDataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
    ...
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But it says that that the resource is not found.

So I try:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControls:ExtendedDataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
    ...
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But it also does not work... So what do I do ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Well mystery is solved :)

My first code above actually works:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControls:ExtendedDataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
    ...
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I thought that it is not working becase VS (or Resharper) showed error in my code saying that resource is not found... Bug in VS (or Resharper) :(

Comment: -.- thought so, do you happen to use the designer?

Comment: Yes, I use it why do you ask ?

Comment: Because it's a piece 'o crap that no one should use unless they have a really good excuse (not knowing how to write XAML ain't one :P), it often claims that something does not work while it indeed does.

Comment: My excuse would be (in addition to the fact that I don't know how to write XAML) that I like to see what the GUI I'm designig acctualy looks like.

Comment: @H.B. But here is one upvote for your comment, you are right :)

Comment: I'd recommend you get Expression Blend, it's *a lot* better than the VS designer, i even use it myself sometimes, still prefer writing XAML directly though because if your code is generated by a designer and you want to go into the code to change something you'll find a chaos you're not familiar with because you obviously did not write the code yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> If you create a style with a
>   TargetType property and base it on
>   another style that also defines a
>   TargetType property, the target type
>   of the derived style must be the same
>   as or be derived from the type of the
>   base style.

Your grid does inherit from DataGrid, right?

Comment: Was wondering what it might be if not that since as you noticed it does work.